# Continuous Function on the Cross Product of Compact Sets

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Here is the question:

Suppose $A$ is a compact Jordan region in $\mathbb{R^p}$, $B$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R^q}$, and f is a continuous function on $B \times A$. Prove that $\int_Af(x,y)dV(y)$ is a continuous function of $x$ on $B$.

I am having trouble understanding where to start with this problem. Would it be in my best interest to try and prove this using the definition of a continuous function, or does the fact that A is Jordan give me a special trick?

Comment: I'm going to guess (perhaps incorrectly) that $A$ was assumed to be a Jordan region not to give a special trick but simply to ensure that the integral makes sense (I take it that Jordan region means Riemann integrable region). With that you should try starting with the definition of continuity and try to use that $A$ is compact.

Comment: Okay, thank you! I started moving in that direction, but this problem feels simple yet tricky. I thought it would be best to ask!

Comment: Note that you will need both the compactness of $A$ and $B$. I forgot to mention $B$ in my first comment.

Comment: Do you know the Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem ?

Comment: No we haven't discussed that this semester!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're asking about where to start I'm going to just give you a hint to help get you started.  Feel free to ask for more...

HINT:
The set $A \times B \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{p+q}$ is compact, as it is the Cartesian product of compact sets.  If you don't know this, it can be shown easily using, for instance, sequential compactness.  Now you know that $f: A \times B \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function on a compact set.  This means that $f$ is actually *uniformly* continuous on $A \times B$.  That is, for $\epsilon >0$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that 
$$
x_1,x_2 \in B, y_1,y_2 \in A \text{ and } \Vert (x_1,y_1)-(x_2,y_2)\Vert_{p+q} < \delta \Rightarrow \vert f(x_1,y_1)-f(x_2,y_2)| < \epsilon. 
$$
I'll trail off here... hope that gets the ball rolling!